# Facebook Audience Network, sending back ads targeting consent status, GDPR

Tags: ios, facebook, ads, mobile-ad-mediation, cookieconsent

I'm using AdMob as a mediation tools among Ads publishers for an iOS app. While I could easily get the way to send back the result of the AdMob consent status form for other technologies, I couldn't find any sample regarding facebook.
So, I implemented it in this way:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKSettings.h>
[FBSDKSettings setLimitEventAndDataUsage: YES]; // or NO
```

Is there anyone out there able to confirm that it is the right way to perform it ? Thanks by advance for your answer.

Comment: I read something about users giving consent through their facebook app, however I am not %100 sure I have seen nothing either about passing consent to the facebook SDK, did you end up figuring it out ?